# How to filter rows using Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

In order to get comfortable with Deedle I made up a CSV file that represents a log of video rentals.

```
   RentedOn,Shop,Title
   12/dec/2013 00:00:00,East,Rambo
   12/dec/2013 00:00:00,West,Rocky
   12/dec/2013 00:00:00,West,Rambo
   12/dec/2013 00:00:00,East,Rambo
   13/dec/2013 00:00:00,East,Rocky
   13/dec/2013 00:00:00,East,Rocky
   13/dec/2013 00:00:00,East,Rocky
   14/dec/2013 00:00:00,West,Rocky 2
```

I have the following function, that groups the rentals by Shop (East or West):

```
let overview =
    __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/rentallog.csv"
    |> Frame.ReadCsv
    |> Frame.groupRowsByString "Shop"
    |> Frame.nest
    |> Series.map (fun dtc df -> 
        df.GetSeries<string>("Title") |> Series.groupBy (fun k v -> v)
        |> Frame.ofColumns |> Frame.countValues )
    |> Frame.ofRows
```

I'd like to be able to filter the rows by the date in the RentedOn col, however, I'm not sure how to do this. I know its probably using the Frame.filterRowValues function but I'm unsure the best way to use this. Any guidance on how to filter would be appreciated.

*Update based on @jeremyh advice*

```
let overview rentedOnDate =
    let addRentedDate (f:Frame<_,_>) = 
        f.AddSeries ("RentedOnDate", f.GetSeries<DateTime>("RentedOn"))
        f
    __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/rentallog.csv"
    |> Frame.ReadCsv
    |> addRentedDate
    |> Frame.filterRowValues (fun row -> row.GetAs<DateTime>("RentedOnDate") = rentedOnDate)
    |> Frame.groupRowsByString "Shop"
    |> Frame.nest
    |> Series.map (fun dtc df -> 
        df.GetSeries<string>("Title") |> Series.groupBy (fun k v -> v)
        |> Frame.ofColumns |> Frame.countValues )
    |> Frame.ofRows
```

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey I think that you might get a faster answer if you add an f# tag to your question too.

I used the following [link](https://gist.github.com/ovatsus/5354187) to answer your question which has some helpful examples.

This is the solution I came up with. Please note that I added a new column RentedOnDate that actually has a DateTime type that I do the filtering on.

```ml
let overview rentedOnDate =
    let rentalLog = 
        __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/rentallog.csv"
        |> Frame.ReadCsv
    rentalLog
    |> Frame.addSeries "RentedOnDate" (rentalLog.GetSeries<DateTime>("RentedOn"))
    |> Frame.filterRowValues (fun row -> row.GetAs<DateTime>("RentedOnDate") = rentedOnDate)
    |> Frame.groupRowsByString "Shop"
    |> Frame.nest
    |> Series.map (fun dtc df -> 
        df.GetSeries<string>("Title") |> Series.groupBy (fun k v -> v)
        |> Frame.ofColumns |> Frame.countValues )
    |> Frame.ofRows

// Testing
overview (DateTime.Parse "12/dec/2013 00:00:00")
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I added the f# tag. The code did not work for me due to the use of 'rentalLog' which is undefined. However, it prompted me to a re-write that I've included in the original question.

Comment: Sorry I have corrected my original answer which should now work